# spring application start up time

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Spring application war file takes more than 15 min to deploy in tomcat server. Our initial finding is that nested dependency of huge number of spring components is attributing to this delay.

Predominantly it is the repository initialization which takes time. Is it possible to lazy load the spring repositories or trigger compilation of named queries before deployment ?

Comment: Depending on which server you are deploying. I know of JBoss Wildfly in which you can add the spring dependencies as modules in the server and load them on request so that you don't have to add them to your application war - making the war lighter.

Comment: I am deploying in tomcat

Comment: Haven't work with Tomcat myself but I think you have to look into how to load external jars in Tomcat at runtime.

Comment: what is the tomcat version, spring version etc

Comment: Annotating repository interfaces with `@Lazy` and then autowiring them lazily as `@Autowired @Lazy` will force the repositories to load lazily with Spring Data JPA > 1.5. However, I have found that the most time is taken in scanning the entities, not initializing repositories, so there may not be a noticeable improvement even after lazy loading the repositories. You can give it a try though.

Comment: How long does it take to startup the app on your local development box?